# Correcting non-linear response of 5050 RGBW LED strips

Tags: led, mosfet, led-strip, non-linear, scaling

I'm a non-engineer asking this question. I'm using a so-called 5050 RGBW LED stips for a project. The level of each colour is controlled by a mosfet transistor (IRLZ34N) which is in turn modulated by values sent from GPIO pins of a computer. The values sent to the mosfets range between 0 (for off) to 255 (for the brightest value). I am using a computer program to control the LEDs and which has colour gradients that can be configured in time to produce transitions between specified colours. The output is in RGB values scaled to between 0 and 255. The problem is that the LEDs (I assume and not the mosfets) have a very non-linear response. For example the values of 1, 2 and 3 jump in brightness quite noticeably whereas in the higher ranges the differences in brightness are less apparent. Consequently the colours generated by the gradients are not well reproduced by the LEDs.

What I'd like to know is if there are any standard curves or formulas to make the response linear for these strips and if not, to ask how I might go about evaluating my own array of corrected values?

I have photographic light meters and a darkroom that might possibly be of use here. I have no technical details on my LED strips, but the model I am using is here:

https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1747103834-fita-led-rgbw-5050-rolo-300-leds-ip65-com-controle-5mt-_JM?searchVariation=71202900380#searchVariation=71202900380&position=5&type=item&tracking_id=a01e81a5-f325-4c6f-9cf3-4ce2780882ae

This strip also has "white" LEDs (the W in the RGBW) which I will likely use independently of the coloured ones.

Comment: This must be RGB question day

Comment: The problem may not be the non-linearity of your LED strip. It's most likely the non-linearity of the human eye. Since you are seeing large variation at the single bit level, you won't be able to remove that with any curve fitting. Sending a 1 will always produce the same current in the LED as well as 2, and 3, and so on until your eyes start to regulate the light level. Once that happens, your eyes are now a more reactive player in the perception of brightness.

Comment: It's possible, but if I use a colour picker to select a shade of yellow, eg. rgb(204, 255, 51), when I send these values to the LEDs I get something much closer to green. Whereas rgb(255, 255, 0), ie at the extremes, gives a decent yellow.

Comment: I think the problen here may be gamma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction

Comment: 1>2 is double, 254>255 is a small increase. you can build a table, or use math like https://github.com/eshkrab/FastLED-esp32/blob/master/colorutils.cpp#L1139 Anecdotally, I can tell you that blue is way to strong on most strips, and green is most responsive to the eye, so it _seems_ rather linear, comparatively speaking. In short, it's actually hard to get good (accurate) color from strips. I would define the brightest white you want to see and can live with, then treat those RGB levels as though they were 255 each; a lowered ceiling. Then pretend the rest is linear; decent, fast, simple.

Comment: Thanks Jasen and dandavis. Interesting, I'll try some things and keep in mind those colour differences.

Comment: Please note that setting all LEDs (the RGB ones) to fully on does not mean the light is white, or even if it is, it may have a hue. The LED brightnesses (current) may not be balanced to produce a white. And due to non-linear response of human eye, for getting 256 linear levels out, you would need to have maybe 10 bit PWM values to mimic the response. We could call it gamma correction as it's similar but it is not actually gamma correction.

Comment: The low end of LED dimming is tricky, but some mitigating methods you can use are keeping input voltage to the LEDs very steady, don't run them at full power or make sure they're well cooled(for glue on strips you can get aluminum channel to mount them in), and for your problems at the low end, in addition to steady voltage, make sure your MOSFET is switching the circuit as sharply as possible.  Having the right operating frequency will also help, fast enough that the eye can't see but slow enough that at low brightness the switching time of the MOSFET is low compared to ON time.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll look in to it. No, the lights won't be on full the whole time and there will be times where they will be off entirely. I found a gamma correction look up table that works pretty well from these pages: https://learn.adafruit.com/led-tricks-gamma-correction/the-quick-fix  - with this I can reproduce the colours in the gradients that I'm using. One problem is that it's an 8 bit control mechanism and it's very 'steppy'. From the same link there's mention of 12-bit LED controllers, so I will look in to these as well. eg. https://www.adafruit.com/product/1429